# ms access - checkbox based on value of textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, checkbox

I am building a report in access 2007, and trying to set a checkbox to true based on the value of a string in a textbox.
For example:  If txtBoxValue = "Injury" then chkBoxValue = True(Checked) Else chkBoxValue = False(unchecked).

This is the value I have in the source control of chkBoxValue.

```
=IIf([txtBoxValue]=”Injury”,1,0)
```

I am new to VBA, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work as the control source of `chkBoxValue`:

```
=([txtBoxValue]="Injury")
```

Be careful about the quotes you use in VBA code.  Notice you used ” (ASCII 148) and I used " (ASCII 34).

**Edit**: As @nicholas pointed out, that control source expression will give you Null when `[txtBoxValue]` is Null.  If you prefer `False` instead, add the `Nz()` function.

```
=(Nz([txtBoxValue],"")="Injury")
```

Comment: This expression can lead to a tri-state checkbox. If the value for [txtBoxValue] is null, the checkbox will be neither checked nor unchecked - it will be shaded gray.

Answer (score 0):

True / False fields use values -1 and 0 in Access. You also have constants TRUE and FALSE.

The control source of the checkbox should read:

```
=IIf([txtBoxValue]="Injury",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: This may be true. If the field is defined in Report Designer view or the expression is defined in Expression builder, single quotes are sufficient. However, double quotes will always work, so I changed it as suggested.